# Logic on disconnect sails.js socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I am using sails.js with the raw API of socket.io. Now when a user disconnects, I want to inform everyone else. Normally I would do something like:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    //disconnect logic
});
```

But I am not sure how I would accomplish this inside of a sails.js controller. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Sails v0.9.8, your `config/sockets.js` file will have both `onConnect` and `onDisconnect` methods that give you access both to the connecting/disconnecting socket and the session.

Answer (score 3):

We can use config/sockets.js as below.

```
 // config/sockets.js
 onConnect: function(session, socket) {
 // If a user is logged in, subscribe to them
 if (session.user) {
   User.subscribe(socket, session.user);
 }

},

 onDisconnect: function(session, socket) {

  // If a user is logged in, unsubscribe from them
  if (session.user) {
  User.unsubscribe(socket, session.user);
  // If the user has no more subscribers, they're offline
   if (User.subscribers(session.user.id).length == 0) {
   console.log("User "+session.user.id+" is gone!");
   // Do something!
   }
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

## For Sails 0.12.3

In `config/sockets.js`

```
  // beforeConnect: function(handshake, cb) {
  //   // `true` allows the connection
  //   return cb(null, true);
  //
  //   // (`false` would reject the connection)
  // },


  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * `afterDisconnect`                                                        *
  *                                                                          *
  * This custom afterDisconnect function will be run each time a socket      *
  * disconnects                                                              *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/
  // afterDisconnect: function(session, socket, cb) {
  //   // By default: do nothing.
  //   return cb();
  // },
```